# Google maps API DirectionsService between lat and long and GeolocationMarker

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, google-maps

I am trying to get the directions services working on google maps api v3.
It is a webapp for smartphones where the user can get directions from where they are (GeolocationMarker) to a static (hardcoded) location defined by a lat and long.
The map centres on the hard coded lat and long, and then I have an icon (gps.png) that onclick should calculate and plot the directions between the two points.
I am not overly strong in javascript and this is essentially a mashup of code...can anyone see what I have done wrong and why this wont work?

Javascript is:

```
<code>
    var map, GeoMarker;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var arena = new google.maps.LatLng(43.684782688659126,-79.2992136269837);
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: arena,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: arena,
        draggable: false,
        raiseOnDrag: false,
        map: map,
        icon: "images/lax-pin1.png",
        labelContent: "Ted Reeve Arena",
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(25, 0),
        labelClass: "pin", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: {opacity: 0.95}
        });
        GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
          GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});
         google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed',                  function(e) {
         map.setCenter(e.latLng);
         map.fitBounds(e.latLngBounds);
         });
         google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
         alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message); 
         });
         GeoMarker.setMap(map);
         }   
        function calcRoute() {
        var request = {
            origin: GeoMarker,
            destination: marker1,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
        });
    }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);      

</code>
```

The html is an onclick div tag for the calcRoute function 
Thanks for any help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error reported:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

for line

```
map.setCenter(e.latLng);
```

Event listener

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function(e) {
    map.setCenter(e.latLng);
    map.fitBounds(e.latLngBounds);
});
```

should be changed to

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function(e) {
    //map.setCenter(e.latLng);
    //map.fitBounds(e.latLngBounds);
    map.setCenter(GeoMarker.getPosition());
    map.fitBounds(GeoMarker.getBounds());
});
```

`request` should be changed to:

```
var request = {
    origin: GeoMarker.getPosition(),
    destination: marker1.getPosition(),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

because origin/destination expects string or valid LatLng

**Update:** I forgot this change: `marker1` has to be changed to global:

```
var map, GeoMarker;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var marker1;
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but it still does not work...nothing happens when the image is clicked...

Comment: <div onclick="calcRoute()"><img src="images/gps.png"></div>  The click works, I have tested with an alert('Hello'); immediately preceding the "var request"

Comment: Okay, I got it to work, but not pretty. This is what I did      `code`    function calcRoute() {
  var arena1 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.684782688659126,-79.2992136269837);
  var request = {
   origin: GeoMarker.getPosition(),
   destination: arena1,
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
  }
  });    `code`

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work...I am not too strong in JS so maybe it was something else.  Adding the variable again, worked though, albeit not the best approach, but it worked.  I don't know what the console log is...I am entirely self taught and use Notepad++ as my dev tool.  I just code and refresh on the iphone.... any suggestions would be well accepted... entirely windows dev platform, no Mac's (yet)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it to work, but not pretty. This is what I did
       function calcRoute() {
        var arena1 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.684782688659126,-79.2992136269837);
        var request = {
            origin: GeoMarker.getPosition(),
            destination: arena1,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
        });